# Nutch 2 with Cassandra as a storage is not crawling data properly

Tags: cassandra, web-crawler, nutch, gora

I am using Nutch 2.x using Cassandra as storage. Currently I am just crawling only one website, and data is getting loaded to Cassandra in byte code format.
When I use readdb command in Nutch, I did get any useful crawling data.

Below are the details of different files and output I am getting:

**========== command to run crawler =====================**

```
bin/crawl urls/ crawlDir/ http://localhost:8983/solr/ 3
```

**======================== seed.txt data ==========================**

```
http://www.ft.com
```

**=== Output of readdb command to read data from cassandra webpage.f table======**

```
~/Documents/Softwares/apache-nutch-2.3/runtime/local$ bin/nutch readdb -dump data -content
~/Documents/Softwares/apache-nutch-2.3/runtime/local/data$ cat part-r-00000 
http://www.ft.com/  key:    com.ft.www:http/
baseUrl:    null    
status: 4 (status_redir_temp)    
fetchTime:  1426888912463
prevFetchTime:  1424296904936
fetchInterval:  2592000
retriesSinceFetch:  0    
modifiedTime:   0    
prevModifiedTime:   0
protocolStatus: (null)    
parseStatus:    (null)
title:  null
score:  1.0
marker _injmrk_ :   y
marker dist :   0    
reprUrl:    null    
batchId:    1424296906-20007    
metadata _csh_ :
```

**===============content of regex-urlfilter.txt ======================**

```
# skip file: ftp: and mailto: urls
-^(file|ftp|mailto):

# skip image and other suffixes we can't yet parse
# for a more extensive coverage use the urlfilter-suffix plugin
-\.(gif|GIF|jpg|JPG|png|PNG|ico|ICO|css|CSS|sit|SIT|eps|EPS|wmf|WMF|zip|ZIP|ppt|PPT|mpg|MPG|xls|XLS|gz|GZ|rpm|RPM|tgz|TGZ|mov|MOV|exe|EXE|jpeg|JPEG|bmp|BMP|js|JS)$

# skip URLs containing certain characters as probable queries, etc.    
-[?*!@=]

# skip URLs with slash-delimited segment that repeats 3+ times, to break loops
-.*(/[^/]+)/[^/]+\1/[^/]+\1/

# accept anything else    
+.
```

**===========content of log file which is bothering me ======================**

```
2015-02-18 13:57:51,253 ERROR store.CassandraStore - 
2015-02-18 13:57:51,253 ERROR store.CassandraStore - [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@653e3e90
2015-02-18 14:01:45,537 INFO  connection.CassandraHostRetryService - Downed Host Retry service started with queue size -1 and retry delay 10s
```

Please let me know if you need more information.
Can someone please help me ?

Thanks in advance.
-Sumant

Comment: You may want to edit your post!  Your code is a little difficult to read, and I think it may need to be formatted.

Comment: do you want me to remove some content ?

Comment: I think you should [check out this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).  It may help you get your question answered.

Comment: done editing.. Hope this is in readable format..

Answer (score 0):

I just started using Nutch and Cassandra today.  I am not receiving the same errors in my log file during a crawl.

Did you double check your nutch-site.xml and gora.properties settings? This is how I currently have my files configured.

nutch-site.xml

```
    <configuration>
    <property>
    <name>http.agent.name</name>
    <value>My Spider</value>
    </property>
    <property> 
       <name>storage.data.store.class</name> 
       <value>org.apache.gora.cassandra.store.CassandraStore</value>
       <description>Default class for storing data</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

gora.properties

```
#############################
# CassandraStore properties #
#############################
gora.datastore.default=org.apache.gora.cassandra.store.CassandraStore
gora.cassandrastore.servers=localhost:9160
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added the same settings in both files. Can you please post content of regex-urlfilter.txt file, then seed.txt file and also the content loaded in your cassandra webpage.f table ? Because I think there is problem in my regex-urlfilter.txt which is skipping the links. Are you able to crawl all the links ?

Comment: My regexurlfilter.txt is exactly like yours, I was testing with one or 2 links one of them being [http://nutch.apache.org/]. I am not getting past the first level either so having the same problem as you except I am not getting the "ERROR store.CassandraStore" report in my logs.  So I am looking at my regex settings as well. I will add my webpage.f table. Sorry thought I could at least get you past the CassadraStore error.

Comment: Thanks. Now I am also not getting the Cassandra error :) Dont know how it got solved :P The problem is now that Nutch is not crawling any link other than the link in seed.txt . Please let me know if you are able to solve this issue. Also if you need any help let me know.

Comment: Chris, any progress ?

Comment: Sumant, back at it today, no success yet. Posted to Nutch user group.